# Assign multiple groups to Ldap User programmatically

Tags: active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

Is it possible to assign multiple groups to a user that's programmatically added to LDAP. If yes, what should be the format followed.

Comment: Your question is too broad to get a usable answer. But you should think of this in the reverse: In Active Directory, you don't assign groups to users. You assign a user as a member of a group. So if you search Google for how to add a user to a group in the language you're using, you will find answers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the right directions.

Comment: Hello @RitheshKrishnan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t assign group/groups to a user. For Correcting you we generally do assign a user as a member of a group.

Hoping you are already setup Active Directory in Your Environment. If not, you can refer this [link](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-active-directory-domain-services-in-windows-server/)

For adding a user to Multiple groups, you can use this PowerShell Script.

```
$Groups = @("group1","group2","groupN")

foreach($group in $groups){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members "UserName"
}
```

Reference : https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2128061-powershell-adding-a-single-user-to-multiple-groups